# React native navigation not rendering after promise

Tags: javascript, react-native

On React Native, I'm using a Promise for the Navigator component on the RightButton function so that I can return a certain icon depending on whether a value in AsyncStorage returns true or false. However the navigator always returns the next case in my switch case, as if it won't wait for my code to finish executing. Is there anything wrong with this implementation, or another way to check AsyncStorage before rendering out my Navigator RightButton.

```
    switch(route.id) {
        case('businessProfile'):

            var _this = this;
            var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

                if (_this.checkBusinessFavourited()) {
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }

            })
                .then(function(isFavourited) { 
                    if (isFavourited) {
                        return (
                            <View style={[ styles.multipleIcons ]}>
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        this.setBusinessAsFavourite(route.business.id)
                                    }}
                                    style={[ styles.navBarButton, styles.iconRightPaddingLarge ]}
                                    >
                                    <IconFA
                                        name='heart'
                                        size={ 25 }
                                        color='#de6262'
                                        style={ styles.icon }
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => this.showShareActionSheet()}
                                    style={ styles.navBarButton }
                                    >
                                    <IconIon
                                        name='ios-upload-outline'
                                        size={ 25 }
                                        color='#696d6f'
                                        style={ styles.icon }
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        );

                    } else {

                        return (
                            <View style={[ styles.multipleIcons ]}>
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        this.setBusinessAsFavourite(route.business.id)
                                    }}
                                    style={[ styles.navBarButton, styles.iconRightPaddingLarge ]}
                                    >
                                    <IconFA
                                        name='heart'
                                        size={ 25 }
                                        color='#ddd'
                                        style={ styles.icon }
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => this.showShareActionSheet()}
                                    style={ styles.navBarButton }
                                    >
                                    <IconIon
                                        name='ios-upload-outline'
                                        size={ 25 }
                                        color='#696d6f'
                                        style={ styles.icon }
                                    />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        );

                    }
                })
```

I've tried something more basic, but my 'checkBusinessFavurited' function gets called 4 times and doesn't always have a value passed, I guess because of race conditions.

```
if (this.checkBusinessFavourited(route.business.id)) {
    return (
        <View><Text>true</Text></View>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <View><Text>false</Text></View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the switch statement doesn't return a component but a Promise. I think you need state to solve this.

```
getInitialState: function(){ return { isFavourited: false } }
```

Then, whenever you can check, maybe on componentWillMount, you do your async operation and as a result of that reset the state.

In the render function you then just use the state.

Comment: That makes sense, however how do I get access to the state in my Navigator RightButton function which sits inside the 'NavigationBarRouteMapper' which goes against my Navigator as a prop as follows: `routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. The renderScene method has access to the component's state it lives in, doesn't it?

Comment: This is how my code looks at the moment (cut down). So I can't get access to any states when I'm in my NavigationBarRouteMapper functions http://pastebin.com/LVKz3ke0

Comment: The Navigator is your root component? Just wrap it in a Component, that returns the Navigator on render. Make the NavigationBarRouteMapper function a method of the wrapper component class (or at least bind it somehow), then the state can live in the wrapper component and NavigationBarRouteMapper has access to it.

Comment: On second thought. You have to have some kind of custom root component. There is now way around it. So where does your Navigator live?

Comment: My root component is a TabBarIOS, which then renders my Navigator component. I just can't seem to check local storage to update any state because of race conditions with it rendering too quick.

Comment: Then let the TabBarIOS not render the Navigator directly, but a wrapper the holds the state. If you want to get fancy you can make it a higher order component :)

Comment: I could be so complex aha! Problem is I'm quite far into a project, which I'll take a lot from for the future, so don't want to alter the structure too much. I've managed to find a workaround, by checking my AsyncStorage key before I push a new scene to the Navigator, then my Navigator has access to the prop 'isFavourited' in my RightButton function :)